# aspectJ; aspect being called when annotated with 'Before' but not with 'Around'

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

so I need to intercept a method when it is being called from within a specific method.

I have this set up, which is working:

```
@Pointcut("execution(*com.connection.sendRequest(..))&& cflow(execution(*com.soapService.sendSoapRequest(..)))")
public void interceptSendRequestOnSoapService() {
};

@Before("interceptSendRequestOnSoapService()") 
public void interceptSoapRequest(JoinPoint point){
...
};
```

this works fine and intercepts like I need it to.

However, the moment I change the anotation to 'Around' as so:

```
@Around("interceptSendRequestOnSoapService()") 
public void interceptSoapRequest(JoinPoint point){
...
};
```

it simply is not called. it never even enters the aspect. It will not intercept. Why, and how can I get it to work on @Around?

Answer (score 0):

well, I seem to have figured it out.

1. I changed my first execution to "call". so call(* com.connection.sendRequest(..))
2. I made my method return an object. so "return joinpoint.proceed()"

Comment: It should not be necessary to change the pointcut from `execution()` to `call()`, unless the target method is outside the reach of your aspect weaver for some reason. The real problem was no. 2: An `@Around` advice needs to return something (unless the target method is `void`) and its parameter should be a `ProceedingJoinPoint`.